# Synchronize Physics on Pool Multiplayer

Tags: sockets, networking, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics-engine

I am making a multiplayer Pool game but i am facing issue with physics synchronization like collision points,collision force. When two clients are connected to a room they exchange data through sockets instead of sending all ball data. I just send input like force vector by which the white ball is hitted. Theoretical,for same action ie.force in this case same response or effect should happen in game but it is not happening in my game.

I apply a known force in one client game connected to room & transfer that force to other client game connected to same room but displacement /position of balls due to collision is different.

I am unable to understand why this happen? Is unity Physics engine behave slight differently on different device or platform?

How can i achieve this?

Comment: This question belongs on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Unity physics is non-deterministic. Also running the physics simulation on two devices rather than sending over the new position, velocity, rotation etc. may introduce inconsistencies caused by lag and device differences, specifically floating point computation inaccuracies.

See also:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/is-unity-physics-deterministic.152825/

This one gives examples regarding device differences in simulation:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/46724/deterministic-physics-same-platform.html

And here you get a description of the workaround in the comments:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/475402/is-physicsraycast-deterministic.html